# trouble with introduction to d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

So I'm just starting d3.js and I keep getting a JavaScript error and I've no idea why. I've just created three circles with svg and want to select them with d3. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>        
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="360" height="180">
        <circle class="little" cx="180" cy="45" r="12"></circle>
        <circle class="little" cx="60" cy="90" r="12"></circle>
        <circle class="little" cx="300" cy="135" r="12"></circle>
    </svg>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var circle = svg.selectAll("circle");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is supposed to select the circles on the page so I can manipulate them but I keep getting a reference error in my Web Console that says svg is not defined? But the introductory tutorial doesn't say anything about defining svg?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: This one: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html

Comment: Yeah, he really doesn't mention it, at least not explicitly, not even in the [introduction](http://d3js.org/). What I found helpful in these situations is having a look at the page source and check the actual code.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing that but was still getting a bit lost unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to actually select the svg element first before using `svg.selectAll`.

```
var svg = d3.select(document.getElementById('sampleSVGId')),
    circle = svg.selectAll('circle');
```

Comment: I wish they would have specified that in the tutorial :(

Comment: Could you link to the tutorial? Objects in general will not magically be created for you unless specified.

Comment: But I understand your pain. Things can be frustrating when you're just beginning in one area and the documentation isn't clear/beginner-friendly.

Comment: It is unfortunate that they don't specify that you have to actually create the `svg` object first, but I think that you should seriously consider looking into learning javascript properly before looking into d3. d3 is quite sophisticated, but something like this problem you ran into would make total sense if you had a solid javascript background. I'm not trying to sound condescending. I'm simply trying to minimize your frustration as you move forward. :-) Check out the book "Javascript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford.

Comment: A more straightforward way is `var svg = d3.select('#sampleSVGId')` or simply `var svg = d3.select('svg')`;

Comment: @Vinay what if `svg` was a d3 global variable? To me it is not straightforward that it is a variable that you should create at first sight.

Comment: I actually agree with you @ChrisJamesC. I take back what I said. In either case, I still think the OP should take the time to get acquainted with javascript before diving into d3. Just personal opinion.